# phpmyadmin cannot upload and read the longblob bin file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, phpmyadmin

I need to upload 20-30 MB longblob bin file to my table.

I have changed the PHPMyAdmin config file:

```
memory_limit = 128M

upload_max_filesize = 100M

post_max_size = 128M
```

The first issue is after I select the file in the PHPMyAdmin insert page. The file seems like doesn't upload successfully. I can still see the size is 0B. And PHPMyAdmin did nothing after I hit "go". The page redirects to the home page but I didn't see the new row.

[image]

I found the tool workbench can insert the file into the table. And I can see the new row in the workbench. But when I go back PHPMyAdmin I got 500 internal server errors if I would like to review this table. All other tables are normal.

[image]

How do I upload the longblob file from PHPMyAdmin and why do I receive the 500 error if I would like to review the table? Did I hit some PHPMyAdmin limitation?

I am very new to PHPMyAdmin and MySQL, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to load more than 16MB into a `LONGBLOB` or `LONGTEXT` because of other constraints.  Are you using `INSERT` or `LOAD DATA` or what?

Comment: Look at the web server error log on your server for details on exactly what the error is.